# How to get all data in CSV from a remote MySQL host using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I know it if fairly easy to use mysqldump or SELECT *INTO OUTFILE.. method to get all the data from a MySQL database into a local directory, but how to achieve the similar using Python and a remote MySQL host.

There is no server directory at the remote location hence not possible tk dump it there on the server. I need to get the csv directly to my computer.

Comment: try [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html)

Answer (score 3):

Consider one of two ways using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module iterating through all tables and writing rows and columns to external csv files (saved as name of table). Both use the [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) package to connect remotely to MySQL but any MySQL database API will work.

**CSV MODULE**

```
import os
import csv
import pymysql

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# OPEN DATABASE CONNECTION
db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=####, db="databasename",
                     user="username", passwd="*****") 
cur = db.cursor() 
# OBTAIN ALL TABLES
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES;")
tables = cur.fetchall()            

for t in tables:
    columns = []
    cur.execute("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS \
                 WHERE table_name = '{0}';".format(t[0]))        

    with open(os.path.join(cd, '{0}.csv'.format(t[0])), 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        # COLUMNS    
        for col in cur.fetchall():
            columns.append(col[0])  
        writer.writerow(columns)    

        # ROWS
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {0};".format(t[0]))            
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            writer.writerow(row)
    f.close()
# CLOSE CURSOR AND DATABASE CONNECTION    
cur.close()
db.close()
```

**PANDAS MODULE**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# OPEN DATABASE CONNECTION
db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=####, db="databasename",
                     user="username", passwd="*****") 
cur = db.cursor() 
# OBTAIN ALL TABLES
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES;")
tables = cur.fetchall()            

for t in tables:
    columns = []
    # IMPORT DATA TO DATA FRAME 
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM {0};".format(t[0]), db)

    # EXPORT DATA FRAME TO CSV
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(cd, '{0}.csv'.format(t[0])), index=False)

# CLOSE CURSOR AND DATABASE CONNECTION    
cur.close()
db.close()
```